# Need Help on Export SQL to CSV through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

I have this PHP script which is supposed to take an SQL Query and output it to a CSV file, I know that when I run it i'm getting the right Statement put in but it does not seem to generate a file to my uploads folder.

Could anyone debug this for me?

```
<?php
function ExportExcel($statement)
{

$filename = "uploads/".strtotime("now").'.csv';

$sql = mysql_query("$statement") or die(mysql_error());

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($num_rows >= 1)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");
$seperator = "";
$comma = "";

foreach ($row as $name => $value)
    {
        $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('', '""', $name);
        $comma = ",";
    }

$seperator .= "\n";
fputs($fp, $seperator);

mysql_data_seek($sql, 0);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        $seperator = "";
        $comma = "";

        foreach ($row as $name => $value) 
            {
                $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('', '""', $value);
                $comma = ",";
            }

        $seperator .= "\n";
        fputs($fp, $seperator);
    }

fclose($fp);
echo "<a href='$filename'>Download</a>";
echo $statement;
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}


}
?>
```

If someone has a similar script that uses mysqli that would be nice

Comment: Have you tried outputting the results to the screen? And are you sure you have the right file permissions to write to the uploads directory?

Comment: Yet another f***ing bad homebrew CSV function...... when will people stop trying to reinvent (badly) something that's already [built-into PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: And just what is `str_replace('', '""', $value);` supposed to replace? Like I say, badly written homebrew

Comment: mark, i'm new to this I was just trying to peace something together based on help i had recieved

Comment: Another problem is probably that you're using the first record received from the database to list the headings, but not using that for its data

Comment: Read the [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function that I linked in my comment, and start by rewriting your code to use that

Comment: Then replace your second `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { ... }` loop with a `do { ... } while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql));` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a example of a export script I use on my apps using MySqli. This will get you started...

```
<?php

    function ExportExcel($statement){

        $output = ""; 
        $sql = mysqli_query($db , $statement);
        $columns_total = mysqli_num_fields($sql);

        // Get The Field Name

        for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $heading = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($sql, $i);
        $output .= '"'.$heading->name.'",';
        }
        $output .="\n";

        // Get Records from the table

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
        }
        $output .="\n";
        }

        // Download the file

        $filename = "CSV_NAME_GOES_HERE.csv";
        header('Content-type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

        echo $output;
        exit;

    }

?>
```

Comment: So the first reply also has a badly-written homebrew CSV..... doesn't anybody ever look at the PHP Docs any more?

Comment: _"There's more than one way to skin a cat"_

Comment: after setting this up when i run it i get a CSV file that has the HTML code for the page that has the form to input the SQL Query

Comment: `$statement` is not correct. `$statement` should be something like `"SELECT * FROM table"` if you run the function `ExportExcel("SELECT * FROM table");` instead of `ExportExcel($statement);` for testing purposes it should work. Obviously replace table with the table name you are trying to read.